# Adding JMenubar to work for both Server-Client based TicTacToe game

Tags: java, swing

I practiced Tic Tac Toe game from a video online. The game is working perfectly. I need to improvise it by providing **JMenuBar** in this way

**JMenuBar** > **File** > **New** && **Exit**

This is the Complete code:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TicTacToeNewExit implements Runnable, ActionListener{

private String ip = "localhost";
private int port = 22222;
private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
private JFrame frame;
private Painter painter;
private Thread thread;
private int WIDTH = 506;
private int HEIGHT = 547;

private JMenuBar jMenuBar;
private JMenu menu;
private JMenuItem newMenuItem, exitMenuItem;

private Socket socket;
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private DataOutputStream dos;
private DataInputStream dis;

private boolean won = false;
private boolean enemyWon = false;
private boolean tie = false;
private boolean accepted = false;
private boolean circle = true;
private boolean unableToCommunicateWithOpponent = false;
private boolean yourTurn = false;

private BufferedImage board;
private BufferedImage redX;
private BufferedImage redCircle;
private BufferedImage blueX;
private BufferedImage blueCircle;

private String[] spaces = new String[9];

private int lengthOfSpace = 160;
private int errors = 0;
private int firstSpot = -1;
private int secondSpot = -1;

private String wonString = "You Won";
private String enemyWonString = "Opponent Won";
private String unableToCommunicateWithOpponentString = "Cannot connect to opponent";
private String tieString = "It's a tie";
private String waitingString = "Waiting for another player.";

private Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 30);
private Font smallerFont = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20);
private Font largerFont = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 40);

private int[][] wins = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};

public TicTacToeNewExit(){
    System.out.println("Enter IP: ");
    ip = scanner.nextLine();        
    System.out.println("Enter port: ");
    port = scanner.nextInt();
    if(port<1025 || port>65523){
        System.out.println("Port Range Problem. Re-enter: ");
        port = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    loadImages();

    painter = new Painter();

    if(!connect()) initializeServer();

    jMenuBar = new JMenuBar();

    menu = new JMenu("File");

    newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New");
    newMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
    newMenuItem.setActionCommand("New");
    newMenuItem.addActionListener(this);
    exitMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    exitMenuItem.setActionCommand("Exit");
    exitMenuItem.addActionListener(this);

    menu.add(newMenuItem);
    menu.add(exitMenuItem);

    jMenuBar.add(menu);

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("TicTacToePractice");
    frame.setContentPane(painter);
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setJMenuBar(jMenuBar);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    thread = new Thread(this, "TicTacToe1");
    thread.start();
}

private void render(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(board, 0, 0, null);

    if(unableToCommunicateWithOpponent){
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.setFont(smallerFont);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        int stringWidth = g2.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(unableToCommunicateWithOpponentString);
        g.drawString(unableToCommunicateWithOpponentString, WIDTH / 2 - stringWidth / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
        return;
    }

    if(accepted){           
        for (int i = 0; i < spaces.length; i++) {
            if (spaces[i] != null) {                    
                int x = (i % 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (i % 3);
                int y = (int) (i / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (i / 3);

                if (spaces[i].equals("X")) {
                    if (circle) {
                        g.drawImage(redX, x, y, null);
                    } else {
                        g.drawImage(blueX, x, y, null);
                    }
                } else if (spaces[i].equals("O")) {
                    if (circle) {
                        g.drawImage(blueCircle, x, y, null);
                    } else {
                        g.drawImage(redCircle, x, y, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (won || enemyWon) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawLine(firstSpot % 3 * lengthOfSpace + 10 * firstSpot % 3 + lengthOfSpace / 2,
                    (int) (firstSpot / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (firstSpot / 3) + lengthOfSpace / 2,
                    secondSpot % 3 * lengthOfSpace + 10 * secondSpot % 3 + lengthOfSpace / 2,
                    (int) (secondSpot / 3) * lengthOfSpace + 10 * (int) (secondSpot / 3) + lengthOfSpace / 2); //(x1,y1) && (x2,y2)
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.setFont(largerFont);
            if (won) {
                int stringWidth = g2.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(wonString);
                g.drawString(wonString, WIDTH / 2 - stringWidth / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
            } else if (enemyWon) {
                int stringWidth = g2.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(enemyWonString);
                g.drawString(enemyWonString, WIDTH / 2 - stringWidth / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
            }
        }
        if (tie) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.setFont(largerFont);
            int stringWidth = g2.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(tieString);
            g.drawString(tieString, WIDTH / 2 - stringWidth / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
        }

    }else{
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.setFont(font);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        int stringWidth = g2.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(waitingString);
        g.drawString(waitingString, WIDTH / 2 - stringWidth / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
        return;
    }
}

private void loadImages() {
    try{
        board = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/board.png"));
        redX = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/redX.png"));
        redCircle = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/redCircle.png"));
        blueX = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/blueX.png"));
        blueCircle = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/blueCircle.png"));
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private boolean connect() {
    try{
        socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        accepted = true;

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Unable to connect to the server. So starting a server on own....Server Started");
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println("Client Connected to Server....");
    return true;
}

private void initializeServer() {
    try{
        serverSocket = new  ServerSocket(port);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    yourTurn = true;
    circle = false;
}   

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        tick();
        painter.repaint();

        if(!circle && !accepted){
            listenToServerRequest();
        }
    }
}

private void listenToServerRequest() {
    Socket socket = null;
    try{
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        accepted = true;
        System.out.println("Client has requested to join. We will accept");
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void tick() {
    if(errors >= 10) System.out.println("Too many errors. Take a step down and get a life");
    if(!yourTurn && !unableToCommunicateWithOpponent){
        try{
            int position = dis.readInt();
            if(circle){
                spaces[position] = "X";
            }
            else{
                spaces[position] = "O";
            }
            checkForEnemyWin();
            checkForTie();
            yourTurn = true;
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            errors++;
        }
    }
}

private void checkForWin(){
    for(int i = 0; i < wins.length; i++){
        if(circle){
            if(spaces[wins[i][0]]=="O" && spaces[wins[i][1]]=="O" && spaces[wins[i][2]]=="O"){
                firstSpot = wins[i][0];
                secondSpot = wins[i][2];
                won = true;
            }
        }else{
            if(spaces[wins[i][0]]=="X" && spaces[wins[i][1]]=="X" && spaces[wins[i][2]]=="X"){
                firstSpot = wins[i][0];
                secondSpot = wins[i][2];
                won = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void checkForEnemyWin(){
    for (int i = 0; i < wins.length; i++) {
        if (circle) {
            if (spaces[wins[i][0]] == "X" && spaces[wins[i][1]] == "X" && spaces[wins[i][2]] == "X") {
                firstSpot = wins[i][0];
                secondSpot = wins[i][2];
                enemyWon = true;
            }
        } else {
            if (spaces[wins[i][0]] == "O" && spaces[wins[i][1]] == "O" && spaces[wins[i][2]] == "O") {
                firstSpot = wins[i][0];
                secondSpot = wins[i][2];
                enemyWon = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void checkForTie(){
    for(int i = 0; i < spaces.length; i++){
        if(spaces[i] == null){
            return;
        }
    }
    tie = true;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TicTacToeNewExit ticTacToe = new TicTacToeNewExit();
}

private class Painter extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Painter(){
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        render(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {    
        if(accepted){
            if(yourTurn && !unableToCommunicateWithOpponent && !won && !enemyWon){
                int x = e.getX()/lengthOfSpace;
                int y = e.getY()/lengthOfSpace;
                y *= 3;

                int position = x+y;

                if(spaces[position] == null){
                    if(!circle) spaces[position] = "X";
                    else spaces[position] = "O";
                    yourTurn = false;
                    repaint();
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

                    try{
                        dos.writeInt(position);
                        dos.flush();
                    }catch(IOException e1){
                        errors++;
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    System.out.println("Data was sent");
                    checkForWin();
                    checkForTie();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
    if(a.getSource() == this.newMenuItem){
        this.frame.setContentPane(painter);
        errors = 0;
        //new TicTacToeNewExit();
    }
    if(a.getSource() == this.exitMenuItem){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

}
```

ActionPerformed is at the very bottom of the code.

I am unable to repaint() the whole server side and client side game using new. Instead the GUI closes and again asks for localhost and port number. How should I proceed in such a way that:

1. if "new" were clicked from either side, a dialogue box would appear on the other side asking the user if they would like to continue for a new game. If "yes", then instead of writing the localhost and port again, it should just refresh the "painter" and start a new game.
2. if "exit" were clicked from either side, a dialogue box would appear on other side displaying that the opponent player has exited.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing in the new's part of the action listener. Wouldn't you simply change the current GUI components back to their original states? If this were my code, I'd use a lot more classes, including MVC structure, and in the new part of my *controller*, I'd simply change my *model* back to its original state. The *view* would be notified of this state change and then would change its display accordingly.

Comment: Looking through your code, I wonder if you will want to re-write and re-structure the entire program. It appears to be doing to much within rendering methods, including program logic, and does not appear to be using event-driven paradigm to its best use. I'm not trying to be harsh, but you have the potential of improving this code significantly.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : I am trying to restructure the code. That won't be a problem. This is my first self-project in Java. Just curious to know why wouldn't making a JMenuBar would help.

Comment: In my mind it is precisely because your program design is broken. But all you appear to be doing is adding `painter` to the contentPane, but it appears that this component **is already within the contentPane**, and so this code appears to be doing nothing of use.